# Haskell function seeking explanation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

```
data BTree a = Empty | Node (BTree a) a (BTree a) -- This is a node-labelled binary tree
```

Could someone please explain be the following Haskell functions?

1. `labels :: BTree a -> [a]`

   ```
   labels Empty = []
   labels (Node left label right) = labels left ++ [label] ++ labels right
   ```
2. `reflect :: BTree a  -> BTree a`

   ```
   reflect Empty = Empty
   reflect (Node left label right) = Node (reflect left) label (reflect right)
   ```

Comment: What do you _think_ they do? What happens when you run them on a small example tree?

Comment: -1: Listen to what Useless says. Before asking a question, please show some of your thought process behind the question. You learn so much more, if you make an effort to think about the answer. If you don't, then you will miss a lot of the fun in programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: some formatting. This is how this code would typically be formatted in Haskell:

```hs
data BTree a = Empty 
             | Node (BTree a) a (BTree a)

labels :: BTree a -> [a]
labels Empty                   = [] 
labels (Node left label right) = labels left ++ [label] ++ labels right

reflect :: BTree a -> BTree a
reflect Empty                   = Empty 
reflect (Node left label right) = Node (reflect left) label (reflect right)
```

(Hint: if you indent code by 4 spaces it will show up properly syntax highlighted).
Now let's go through it:

```hs
data BTree a = Empty 
             | Node (BTree a) a (BTree a)
```

Defines a new 'parametric' data type. It is called parametric because of the small `a` which is a type parameter. This means that `a` can be replaced by any other type, for example `Int`, `Double`, `String`, or whatever. Think templates in C++ or generics in Java. `Empty` and `Node` are called the *constructors* of the data type. A `BTree a` can either be `Empty` or (that's what `|` symbolizes) contain a `Node` which contains a `BTree a` an `a` and another `BTree a`. The definition is *recursive* because the datatype (`BTree a`) shows up in its own definition.

```hs
labels :: BTree a -> [a]
labels Empty                   = [] 
labels (Node left label right) = labels left ++ [label] ++ labels right
```

`labels` collects all values that are contained in the tree. The first line is the type declaration: It takes a binary tree with `a` nodes (`BTree a`) and maps that to a list of `a`s (`[a]`). The type alone already gives you a good idea of what might be going on.

The next two lines are what are called *pattern matches*. These are similar to `case` statements in other languages: you distinguish different possibilities and then choose the appropriate case (they are much more powerful though). You should note how they correspond exactly to the two constructors that `BTree a` has. If we are at an `Empty` node then we'll just return an empty list (`[]`). Otherwise we'll fall through to the next line and have a `Node` which must have a `BTree a` an `a` and a `BTree a` which we bind to `left`, `label`, and `right`. We might have called `left`, `label` and `right` whatever we wanted, but these are intuitive.

Now `left` and `right` are again of type `BTree a` so we can call `labels` on both and expect them to return a list of `a`s, i.e. `[a]`. So labels is also *recursive* because it calls itself in its definition. This is a very powerful technique which is used a lot in Haskell. `labels` then concatenates the list it got from `labels left`, one which only contains the current label (`[label]`) and then one it got from `labels right`. So we can effectively conclude that it joins the labels from the left subtree with the current label and the ones from the right subtree and puts it all into a list.

```hs
reflect :: BTree a -> BTree a
reflect Empty                   = Empty 
reflect (Node left label right) = Node (reflect left) label (reflect right)
```

Works pretty much the same way as `labels`, except that it returns a tree of the labels and not a list. So effectively, this does nothing, it is a bit of an expensive identity function. But it is a template for something more powerful. For example, you could quite easily pass another function to `reflect` and apply it to each of its elements.

Comment: I think the second equation of `reflect` was meant to be `reflect (Node left label right) = Node (reflect right) label (reflect left)` and the OP mis-copied.